# "Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal" cmdlet not recognize service priciple ID

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-runbook

I'm migrating Run As Account in my Azure Runbook to Managed Identity, everything seems smooth except for the Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal cmdlet (in AzureADPreview module). That cmdlet doesn't recognize my existing service principle ID. The Managed-Identity account works well with other cmdlets.

The Runbook is PowerShell 5.1 and this is my code:

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview

#Connect Managed-Identity Account
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "7a948a55-81e4-44fb-a6f0-ae11082d9125"

#Connect AzureAD
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

#The cmdlet 
Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal -Id 86ddbfda-9004-4b3a-b199-b1223c556cb1 -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $False
```

The Runbook failed at AzureADMSServicePrincipal cmdlet with error:
`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

The Service Principle ID exists in AzureAD and exactly the same cmdlet is working fine with Run As Account.

Please help to check why it fails.

### I tried to removed and installed the AzureADPreview module again. I tried to create the Runbook with PowerShell 7.x. All didn't work.
All other cmdlets working well with the Identity, only AzureADMSServicePrincipal fails.

**Update 1:**

Following @Imran reply, I've connected to MS Graph successfully but I received "[Service_InternalServerError] : Encountered an internal server error." when running the "Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params" command.
My code is like below:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context $AzureContext = Set-AzContext
-SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

$AppId = 'appid' $TenantId = 'tenantid' $servicePrincipalId = 'serviceId'

$cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "resourcename"
-AutomationAccountName "accname" -Name "certname").Thumbprint Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint $cert -TenantId $TenantId
-ClientId $AppId

$params = @{
        SLBApplications = @{
            "@odata.type" = "#Microsoft.DirectoryServices.CustomSecurityAttributeValue"
             attr1 ="test"
             attr2="test"
        }
    }

Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId
-BodyParameter $params
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I run `AzureADMSServicePrincipal` cmdlet I got the same error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

To resolve the issue make you of below modified script like below:

```c
Import-Module AzureADPreview

#Connect Managed-Identity Account
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "7a948a55-81e4-4XXXXX"

#Connect AzureAD
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
#The cmdlet 
Set-AzureADServicePrincipal -objectId d985b6-bcbd-e4XXXXX -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $false
```

When I run in Automation runbook 5.1 PowerShell I got result successfully like below:

[image]

> ***Note*** that: Make use of `Set-AzureADServicePrincipal` instead of `Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal` command

***Reference***:

[Set-AzureADServicePrincipal (AzureAD) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0)

### Update

In my case, I used certificate-based authentication by importing **Microsoft.Graph modules.**

In your automation account, import  `Microsoft.Graph.Authentication`  and  `Microsoft.Graph.Applications`  modules like this:

[image: Automation modules ss]

You can create certificate by following this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate#create-and-export-your-public-certificate)

[image: powershell output cer ss]

In Azure AD app, upload that **`.cer`** certificate like this:

[image: Azure AD app certificate ss]

Make sure to grant **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** permission in that app

[image: Azure AD app API permissions ss]

Now, upload **`.pfx`** certificate to automation account:

[image: automation cer ss]

You need to turn on ***system-assigned managed identity*** and assign proper RBAC role to fetch certificate. (In my case, I assigned ***Contributor*** role)

Now, run below PowerShell code in your runbook:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

$AppId = 'appId'
$TenantId = 'tenantID'
$servicePrincipalId = 'spObjId'

$cert = (Get-AzAutomationCertificate -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -AutomationAccountName "testautomation" -Name "sricert").Thumbprint
Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint $cert -TenantId $TenantId -ClientId $AppId

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

$params = @{
    appRoleAssignmentRequired = $true
}

Update-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $servicePrincipalId -BodyParameter $params
```

[image: AutomationOutput ss]

[image]

You can refer this  [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/custom-security-attributes-examples?tabs=powershell#example-2-assign-a-custom-security-attribute-with-a-string-value-to-a-service-principal)  to set custom attributes by replacing code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I have to use the Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal cmdlet because after that I set custom attributes with `Set-AzureADMSServicePrincipal -Id $ServiceObjectID -CustomSecurityAttributes $attributes`. The Set-AzureADServicePrincipal can't use to set custom attributes.

Comment: @ThaoLe check the updated answer

Comment: Sorry for late response, I had to test many times before replying. Please check the Update 1 in my question. Many thanks.